# How does LCP help in finding the number of occurrences of a pattern?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, pattern-matching, suffix-array

I have read that the **Longest Common Prefix (LCP)** could be used to find the number of occurrences of a pattern in a string.

Specifically, you just need to create the suffix array of the text, sort it, and then instead of doing binary search to find the range so that you can figure out the number of occurrences, you simply compute the LCP for each successive entry in the suffix array.

Although using binary search to find the number of occurrences of a pattern is obvious I can't figure out how the LCP helps find the number of occurrences here.

For example for this suffix array for `banana`:

```
LCP  Suffix entry
N/A  a  
1    ana  
3    anana  
0    banana  
0    na  
2    nana
```

How does the LCP help find the number of occurrences of a substring like "banana" or "na" is not obvious to me.

Any help figuring out how LCP helps here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I do not know any way of using the LCP array *instead* of carrying out a binary search, but I believe what you refer to is the technique described by Udi Manber and Gene Myers in [Suffix arrays: a new method for on-line string searches](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=suffix+arrays+a+new+method+for+on-line+string+searches&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5).

(Note: The below explanation has been copied into a Wikipedia article on 9th April 2014, see [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=LCP_array&diff=603491647&oldid=603484606). If you look at the revision history here and on Wikipedia, you'll see that the one here was written first. Please don't insert comments like "taken from Wikipedia" into my answer.)

The idea is this: In order to find the number of occurrences of a given string P (length m) in a text T (length N),

- You use binary search against the suffix array of T (just like you suggested)
- But you **speed it up** using the LCP array as auxiliary data structure. More specifically, you generate a special version of the LCP array (I will call it LCP-LR below) and use that.

The issue with using standard binary search (*without* the LCP information) is that in **each of the O(log N) comparisons** you need to make, you compare P to the current entry of the suffix array, which means a **full string comparison** of up to m characters. So the complexity is O(m*log N).

The LCP-LR array helps improve this to O(m+log N), in the following way:

- At any point during the binary search algorithm, you consider, as usual, a range (L,...,R) of the suffix array and its central point M, and decide whether you continue your search in the left sub-range (L,...,M) or in the right sub-range (M,...,R).
- In order to make the decision, you compare P to the string at M. If P is identical to M, you are done, but if not, you will have compared the first k characters of P and then decided whether P is lexicographically smaller or larger than M. Let's assume the outcome is that P is larger than M.
- So, in the **next step**, you consider (M,...,R) and a new central point M' in the middle:

  ```
                M ...... M' ...... R
                |
         we know:
            lcp(P,M)==k
  ```

  The **trick** now is that LCP-LR is precomputed such that a O(1)-lookup tells you the longest common prefix of M and M', lcp(M,M').

  You know already (from the previous step) that M itself has a prefix of k characters in common with P: lcp(P,M)=k. Now there are three possibilities:

  - Case 1: k < lcp(M,M'), i.e. P has *fewer* prefix characters in common with M than M has in common with M'. This means the (k+1)-th character of M' is the same as that of M, and since P is lexicographically larger than M, it must be lexicographically larger than M', too. So we continue in the right half (M',...,R).
  - Case 2: k > lcp(M,M'), i.e. P has *more* prefix characters in common with M than M has in common with M'. Consequently, if we were to compare P to M', the common prefix would be smaller than k, and M' would be lexicographically larger than P, so, *without actually making the comparison*, we continue in the left half (M,...,M').
  - Case 3: k == lcp(M,M'). So M and M' are both identical with P in the first k characters. To decide whether we continue in the left or right half, it suffices to compare P to M' **starting from the (k+1)-th character**.
- We continue recursively.

The overall effect is that **no character of P is compared to any character of the text more than once**. The total number of character comparisons is bounded by m, so the total complexity is indeed O(m+log N).

Obviously, the key remaining question is how did we precompute LCP-LR so it is able to tell us in O(1) time the lcp between any two entries of the suffix array? As you said, the standard LCP array tells you the lcp of **consecutive entries** only, i.e. lcp(x-1,x) for any x. But M and M' in the description above are not necessarily consecutive entries, so how is that done?

The key to this is to realize that only certain ranges (L,...,R) will ever occur during the binary search: It always starts with (0,...,N) and divides that at the center, and then continues either left or right and divide that half again and so forth. If you think of it: Every entry of the suffix array occurs as central point of exactly one possible range during binary search. So there are exactly N distinct ranges (L...M...R) that can possibly play a role during binary search, and it suffices to precompute lcp(L,M) and lcp(M,R) for those N possible ranges. So that is 2*N distinct precomputed values, hence LCP-LR is O(N) in size.

Moreover, there is a straight-forward recursive algorithm to compute the 2*N values of LCP-LR in O(N) time from the standard LCP array – I'd suggest posting a separate question if you need a detailed description of that.

**To sum up:**

- It is possible to compute LCP-LR in O(N) time and O(2*N)=O(N) space from LCP
- **Using LCP-LR during binary search  helps accelerate the search procedure** from O(M*log N) to O(M+log N)
- As you suggested, you can use two binary searches to determine the left and right end of the match range for P, and the length of the match range corresponds with the number of occurrences for P.

Comment: +1!This is exactly what I was looking for!Thank you very much for your thorough explanation!One question:To compute the suffix array, I had in mind populating an array of size `N` (same as size of suffix array essentially) and just do a linear calculation for pairs of suffixes to find the `LCP`.Your description of `straight-forward recursive algorithm...` got me curious.How should I ask about this in a separate thread?

Comment: What I meant was an algorithm that transforms the standard LCP into the special LCP-LR needed here. To ask for that on SO, best ask for "an algorithm to create the Manber/Myer LCP array from the standard LCP" or something like that. But if you are looking for a direct algorithm that computes the LCP-LR right from the suffix array, I am not so sure. You can ask for that too, but I don't know if there is a good answer.

Comment: May be I misunderstand something here, but if I have an array `LCP[N]` that each entry has the `LCP` of the `Suffix[i]` and `Suffix[i-1]` (capturing the `N/A`,`1`,`3`,`0` etc from my OP) I am still able to do the algorithm you describe, right?You are just saying that the optimal way is a different kind of `LCP` array the `LCP LR`?

Comment: Right.. what you have is what I call the standard LCP (because many suffix array packages, such as [jSuffixArrays](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/jsuffixarrays.html) come with this standard LCP built-in). It can be constructed along with the suffix array construction very efficiently. But for the algorithm described above, you must transform that to LCP-LR -- or else you won't get O(m+log N).

Comment: @jogojapan The link in your answer is dead. Also, are you aware of any reference implementations for building the LCP and LCP-LR?

Comment: @robjb Thanks for the comment. I've corrected the link (it's a link to a Google Scholar search, the idea being that it would never turn into a dead link; I must have copied the link wrongly in the first place). Unfortunately, I don't know any implementation that includes the LCP-LR.

Comment: @jogojapan Super answer - well explained and easy to understand - thanks! :)

Comment: Here is a discussion abut LCP-LR implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768429/implementation-of-string-pattern-matching-using-suffix-array-and-lcp-lr/

Comment: @jogojapan: And here is a discussion about the matching algorithm. I am kind of stuck there, because it feels like the algo as explained in the paper seems to have a principal flaw :-/ 
Maybe you can help us to understand what the problem is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444226/understanding-the-algorithm-for-pattern-matching-using-an-lcp-array

Comment: @jogojapan I cannot still get the idea of how to count the number of occurrences of a pattern with two binary searches. I perform one binary search and i found a random occurrence of the pattern if any. How i proceed next?

Comment: @curious What I had in mind is essentially the approach described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25966181/777186 That's for integers, so you have to make adjustments to fit it into the solution above for strings.

Comment: @jemshit-iskenderov I reversed your edit, which modified my text by inserting a claim that it was taken from Wikipedia. It was not taken from Wikipedia. The section in the Wikipedia article that you apparently found was written on 9th April 2014 (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=LCP_array&diff=603491647&oldid=603484606)), more than a year after I wrote my answer here. Somebody copied my answer into the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

The Longest Common Prefix (LCP) is the Lowest Common Ancestor (LCA) in a suffix tree.  Once you have the Lowest Common Ancestor, you can count the number of nodes that branch out from the LCA.  This will give you the number of occurrences of a pattern in the suffix tree.  This is the relationship between the LCP and LCA.