# Binary Search Multiple Same Items & Count Occurence

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search, coding-efficiency

My Question is simple from the below  code how do you implement an algorithm that will search the same occurence of items after the mid value is found? Assuming the data is sorted.

I would appreciate you guys help me implementing based on my code below. **I have approaches such as adding an extra function such as an exponential search but I am afraid that will ruin the time complexity of the algorithm.**

**I would like you guys to implement an algorithm that looks for multiple same items and count their occurrence as well as it will allows the time complexity of the code below remains as O(LOG N)**

```
private boolean binarySearchComparator(TYPE key) {

            int low = 0;

            int high = count - 1;

            while (low <= high) {

                int mid = (low + high) / 2;

                TYPE midVal = list[mid];

                int cmp = comparator.compare(midVal, key);

                if (cmp < 0)
                    low = mid + 1;

                else if (cmp > 0)
                    high = mid - 1;

                else
                    return true;

    }
}
```

My Full Codes here Take a look.

**Sorted List Interface**

```
public interface SortedListInterface <TYPE extends Comparable<TYPE>> {


    public boolean add(TYPE element);


    public TYPE get(int index);


    public int search(TYPE element);


    public TYPE remove(int index);


    public void clear();




public int getLength();


public boolean isEmpty();


public boolean isFull();
```

}

**SearchComparator Class**

```
public class MobileSearch implements Comparator<Student>{


    private String type;

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }




    @Override
    public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {


        int result = 0;



        if(this.type.equals("mobile")){
            result = student1.getMobileNo().compareTo(student2.getMobileNo());
            System.out.print(result+"mobile");
        }

        else if(this.type.equals("name")){
            result = student1.getName().getFullName().compareTo(student2.getName().getFullName());
             System.out.println(result+"name");
        }

        else if(this.type.equals("group")){

                 result = student1.getGroup().compareTo(student2.getGroup());
                 System.out.print(result+"group");

             }



        return result;
    }

}
```

**SortedArrayList Implementation**

```
public class SortedArrayList<TYPE extends Comparable<TYPE>> implements SortedListInterface<TYPE>{

  //Data Types  

  private TYPE[] list;
  private int length;
  private static final int SIZE = 10;

  private Comparator<? super TYPE> comparator;
  private int count;


  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SortedArrayList(Comparator<? super TYPE> c) {
        comparator = c;
        list = (TYPE[]) new Comparable[SIZE]; // No way to verify that 'list' only contains instances of 'T'.

        /* NOTE: Following is not allowed.
        list = new T[SIZE]; // Cannot create a generic array of T
        */
    }




  // Constructors

  public SortedArrayList() {
    this(SIZE);
  }

  public SortedArrayList(int size) {
    length = 0;
    list = (TYPE[]) new Comparable[SIZE]; // an array of instances of a class implementing Comparable interface and able to use compareto method but its overidden instead
  }



  // Setter & Getters

  @Override
  public int getLength() {
    return length;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return length == 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isFull() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void clear() {
    length = 0;
  }


  // Array Expansion

  private boolean isArrayFull() {
    return length == list.length;
  }

  private void expandArray() {
    TYPE[] oldList = list;
    int oldSize = oldList.length;

    list = (TYPE[]) new Object[2 * oldSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++) // copy old array elements into new array elements
      list[i] = oldList[i];

  }




  // ADT METHODs


  // Add New Elements Function


  @Override
//    public boolean add(TYPE element) {
//        int i = 0;
//
//        while (i < length && element.compareTo(list[i]) > 0) // return 0 with equal , return more than 1 if element larger than list[i] , return -1 if less
//        {
//            i++;
//        }
//
//        makeRoom(i + 1);
//        list[i] = element;
//        length++;
//        return true;
//    }


  public boolean add(TYPE element) {

        boolean result = false;
        if (count == 0) {
            list[0] = element;
            count = 1;
            result = true;
        }
        else {
            if (!isFull()) {
                int i = 0;
                while (list[i] != null) {
                    if (element.compareTo(list[i]) < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (list[i] != null) {
                    for (int j = count - 1; j >= i; j--) {
                        list[j + 1] = list[j];
                    }
                }
                list[i] = element;
                count++;
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


  private void makeRoom(int index) {  // accepts given index
    int newIndex = index - 1;
    int lastIndex = length - 1;

    for (int i = lastIndex; i >= newIndex; i--) 
      list[i + 1] = list[i];

  }



  //Remove Elements Function

  @Override
  public TYPE remove(int index) {  // accepts given index

    TYPE result = null;

    if ( index >= 1 && index <= length ) {

      result = list[index - 1];

      if (index < length) 
        removeGap(index);

      length--;
    }

    return result;
  }

  private void removeGap(int index) { // accepts given index and remove the gap where the element its removed

    int removedIndex = index - 1;
    int lastIndex = length - 1;

    for (int i = removedIndex; i < lastIndex; i++) 
      list[i] = list[i + 1]; // shifts elements back to remove the gap

  }


  // Get Element

  @Override
  public TYPE get(int index) { // accepts given index and return the object

    TYPE object = null;

    if ( index >= 1 && index <= length) 
      object = list[index - 1];

    return object;

  }


  // Search Algorithms

  @Override
// public boolean search(TYPE element) {
//    boolean found = false;
//    
//    int lo = 0;
//    int hi = count - 1;
//    
//    while (lo <= hi) {
//        int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
//        if (list[mid].compareTo(element) < 0) {
//            lo = mid + 1;
//        }
//        else if (list[mid].compareTo(element) > 0) {
//            hi = mid - 1;
//        }
//        else if (list[mid].compareTo(element) == 0) {
//            found = true;
//            break;
//        }
//          return found
//    }

  public int search(TYPE element) {

            return exponentialSearch(element);

    }



  private boolean binarySearchComparable(TYPE element) {
        boolean found = false;
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = count - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
            if (list[mid].compareTo(element) < 0) {
                lo = mid + 1;
            }
            else if (list[mid].compareTo(element) > 0) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            }
            else if (list[mid].compareTo(element) == 0) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Single");
        return found;
    }


    private int exponentialSearch(TYPE key){

        int ind = binarySearchComparator(key);


     // If element is not present 
        if (ind == -1) 
            return -1; 

        // Count elements on left side. 
        int count = 1; 
        int left = ind - 1; 
        int i = 1;
        while (left >= 0 && (comparator.compare(list[left], key)) == 0) 
        { 
//            lol[i] = list[left];
            System.out.println(left+"lefttest");
            i++;
            count++; 
            left--; 

        } 

        // Count elements  
        // on right side. 
        int right = ind + 1; 

        try{


        while (right < list.length && (comparator.compare(list[right], key)) == 0) 
        { 
            System.out.println(right+"righttest");
//            lol[i] = arr[right];
            i++;
            count++; 
            right++; 



        } 

        }catch(Exception e){

        }


        return count; 
    }

    private int binarySearchComparator(TYPE key) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = count - 1;

        while (low <= high) {

            int mid = (low + high) / 2 ;
            TYPE midVal = list[mid];
            int cmp = comparator.compare(midVal, key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                return mid; // key found
        }

        return -1;  // key not found.
    }













  //To String Method

  @Override
  public String toString() {

    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
      result += list[i] + "\n";

    return result;

  }



}
```

**Name Class**

```
public class Name {

    // Data Types

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;


    // Constructors

    public Name() {
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // setter

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // getter

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFullName(){
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name{" + "firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + '}';
    }







}
```

**Student Class**

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{


   // Data Types 

   private String studID; 
   private Name name;
   private String gender;
   private String icNo;
   private String mobileNo;
   private Course course;
   private String group;
   private String dOB;


   // Constructors

   public Student() {
   }


    public Student(String studID, Name name, String gender, String icNo, String mobileNo, Course course, String group, String dOB) {
        this.studID = studID;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.icNo = icNo;
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
        this.course = course;
        this.group = group;
        this.dOB = dOB;
    }



   public Student(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


   // setter


    public void setStudID(String studID) {
        this.studID = studID;
    }

   public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void setIcNo(String icNo) {
        this.icNo = icNo;
    }

    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public void setdOB(String dOB) {
        this.dOB = dOB;
    }


    // getter

    public String getStudID() {
        return studID;
    }

    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String getIcNo() {
        return icNo;
    }

    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public String getdOB() {
        return dOB;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + ", icNo=" + icNo + ", mobileNo=" + mobileNo + ", course=" + course + ", group=" + group + ", dOB=" + dOB + '}';
    }


   @Override
   public int compareTo(Student object) { // Sort according to name if name same then sort according to gender and so on.

    int c = this.name.getFullName().compareTo(object.getName().getFullName());

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.gender.compareTo(object.getGender()); 

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.icNo.compareTo(object.getIcNo());  

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.mobileNo.compareTo(object.getMobileNo());

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.group.compareTo(object.getGroup());

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.dOB.compareTo(object.getdOB());

    return c;

  }

   public static Student[] sort(Student[] object,String category){


       Student[] array;

       if(category.equals("ID")){
         for (int i=1; i < object.length; i++) {
           for(int j = 0 ; j < object.length - i ; j++)
               if( (object[j].getGender().compareTo(object[j+1].getGender())) > 0 ){
                    Student lol = object[j];
                    object[j] = object[j+1];
                    object[j+1] = lol;
              }
       }



   }
        array = object;
       return array;
  }


}
```

**Course Class**

```
public class Course {


    // Data Types

    private String courseCode;
    private String courseName;
    private double courseFee;


    // Constructors

    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(String courseCode, String courseName, double courseFee) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseFee = courseFee;
    }

    // setter

    public void setCourseCode(String courseCode) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseFee(double courseFee) {
        this.courseFee = courseFee;
    }


    // getter

    public String getCourseCode() {
        return courseCode;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public double getCourseFee() {
        return courseFee;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CourseCode = " + courseCode + "Course Name = " + courseName + "Course Fee = " + courseFee;
    }




}
```

Comment: You must take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12144802/4796021

Comment: Hmmm do you know how to implement , yes I did take a look. Still most of their approach are recursive approach instead of iterative approach for binary search. Just can’t seem to figure out.

Comment: The key idea is to look for the first position (left) and the last position (right) of the key element.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera , hmm for some reason all I can think of is implementing an additional exponential search combined binary to do the trick. Not sure what others will do. I assume they have much more better approach than me.

Comment: @Cash- generally, for tree operations, recursive approaches are favored, because the structure itself is defined recursively. To count the number of items stored, you can for instance implement a field called 'count' in each node, and update it upon insertion/deletion of elements in your tree

Comment: I have implemented my own approach will edit the code later. You guys check out if it’s a good one or will it affect the time complexity. And by the way my menthols binary search method not binary search tree

Comment: @Cash You want to find frequency of one value in a sorted list, like for instance, say target is `3`, so answer for `[1,1,3,3,3,3,3,8,9,10,12,14]` is `5`?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question well. It is indeed possible to have a O(log n) algorithm to count these multiple occurrences, I'll start writing an answer soon.

Comment: @vivek_23 , Yes. But try and implement with my code above. Since my code above is searching for objects based attributes such as name , mobile phone etc.

Comment: @m.raynal , alright man. Thank you. I appreciate it!

Comment: @Cash can you add an example of a sample case and your expected output? I am kinda confused.

Comment: @vivek_23 , nevermind I will add my approach later. Do you want my class codes and everything? I can upload it for you to analyze.

Comment: @Cash I just need a basic example of what are those objects? And I am confused as to how that would change the logic of binary search if we were to search by some attribute say `name` or `phone number` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 , I have uploaded my codes. Its hard to explain in words maybe from my code you can understand. But now I got to go so yeah I will explain to you once I am free.

Comment: @vivek_23 , let me just try and explain now.
Based on my binary search function above , take a look at my ADT SortedArrayList

My original function will call binary search and it will count the occurrence using my way.

exponentialSearch() <-- take a look at this one trace it to the binaryseachcomparator.

Maybe you will get the overall picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of occurences of an element in an ordered array/list using binary search by finding the minimum and maximum index of the element in the list.
I wrote (blindly, untested since I don't have the rest of your code) two functions, that can find respectively the min and max index of the element in the list

```
private int getMinIdx(TYPE key, int low, int high) {
    int lowVal = list[low];
    if ((low == high) || (low == high-1)) {
        if (comparator.compare(lowVal, key) == 0) {
            return low;
        } else {
            return high;
        }
    }
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int midVal = list[mid];
    int cmp = comparator.compare(midVal, key);
    if (cmp < 0) {
        return getMinIdx(key, mid, high);
    } else {
        return getMinIdx(key, low, mid);
    }
}

private int getMaxIdx(TYPE key, int low, int high) {
    int highVal = list[high];
    if ((low == high) || (low == high-1)) {
        if (comparator.compare(highVal, key) == 0) {
             return high;
        } else {
            return low;
        }
    }
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int midVal = list[mid];
    int cmp = comparator.compare(midVal, key);
    if (cmp > 0) {
        return getMaxIdx(key, low, mid);
    } else {
        return getMaxIdx(key, mid, high);
    }
}
```

Take note that they work if and only if the element is located in the list. But since you have a function that already answers that, all you'll have to do is  use it before calling those two. They're binary search based, so each of them runs in `O(log n)`.
I don't offer you any guarantee about the code I wrote above (especially the `return` part, it might need an additional check).
Nevertheless, the method to count the numbers is legit and binary search based, so I'm pretty sure that you'll have no problems understanding the principle and adapting it to your code.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Apparently I can't test the implementation now. But I have added all my necessary codes for you to re-adjust.

My original approach in counting occurence is in there too. 
From my original codes feel free to readjust your implementation.

Comment: Apparently I still can't figure out how to implement a display in your code. Say I count occurence at the same time I store the found data in an array to display it later to the user.

This is like a filtering / searching function.

Comment: Hopefully you can help me. Thanks!