# Algorithms task about finding not unique number in array

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm new at algorithms and want to know how to solve this task. A detailed Java solution is desirable.

You have been given an integer n≥2 and an integer array A[0..n−1] which is sorted in
nondecreasing order . All numbers repeat 1 time but one number repeats 2 times, how do you find the number that repeat 2 times. Using data structures and built-in functions was not allowed. Complexity of algorithm should be O(lg(n))

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with repeat one time? Is one number that only repeats one time unique in the array, or are there two instances?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding multiple entries with binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144802/finding-multiple-entries-with-binary-search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom binary search algorithm.

We can observe that if there would be *only* values that repeated once (which occur twice), then the size of the array is even, and we have for each *even* index `i`: `A[i] == A[i+1]`.

Since there is exactly one *triplet*, the array's size is odd, and so if we find an even index `i` for which `A[i] == A[i+1]` we know that the triplet did not occur at the *left* side of `i`. If however `A[i] != A[i+1]`, then we are sure the triplet occurred at the left side of `i`.

This is all we need to perform a binary search. We should just make sure we always make our checks at *even* indices.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function binarySearchTriplet(arr) {
    let lo = 0, hi = arr.length - 1; // even
    while (lo < hi) {
        // Take mid, but force it to be even
        mid = (lo + hi) >> 2 << 1;
        if (arr[mid] === arr[mid+1]) {
            lo = mid + 2;
        } else {
            hi = mid;
        }
    }
    return arr[lo];
}

let arr = [1,1,4,4,4,5,5,7,7,2,2,6,6,8,8];
console.log(binarySearchTriplet(arr)); // 4
```