# Implementation of string pattern matching using Suffix Array and LCP(-LR)

Tags: c++, c, string, pattern-matching

During the last weeks I tried to figure out how to efficiently find a string pattern within another string.

I found out that for a long time, the most efficient way would have been using a suffix tree. However, since this data structure is very expensive in space, I studied the use of suffix arrays further (which use far less space). Different papers such as "Suffix Arrays: A new method for on-line string searches" (Manber & Myers, 1993) state, that  searching for a substring can be realised in O(P+log(N)) (where P is the length of the pattern and N is length of the string) by using binary search and suffix arrays along with LCP arrays.

I especially studied the latter paper to understand the search algorithm. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11374737/3722347) did a great job in helping me understand the algorithm (and incidentally made it into the [LCP Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array#LCP_Array_usage_in_finding_the_number_of_occurrences_of_a_pattern)).

But I am still looking for an way to implement this algorithm. Especially the construction of the mentioned LCP-LR arrays seems very complicated.

*References:*

Manber & Myers, 1993: Manber, Udi ; Myers, Gene, SIAM Journal on Computing, 1993, Vol.22(5), pp.935-948, http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0222058

**UPDATE 1**

Just to emphasize on what I am interested in: I understood LCP arrays and I found ways to implement them. However, the "plain" LCP array would not be appropriate for efficient pattern matching (as described in the reference). Thus I am interested in implementing LCP-LR arrays  which seems much more complicated than just implementing an LCP array

**UPDATE 2**

Added link to referenced paper

Comment: What language would you need the implementation in?

Comment: C/C++ would be fine. Or any language implementation that is portable to C/C++ with less effort than implementing it on my own

Comment: I've modified the question slightly, as requests for implementations and libraries are generally off-topic here (though given you've evidently done some good research, readers may be somewhat more indulgent).

Comment: @Paddre a c implementation would be very different from a c++ one, so please choose a language to get better help.

Comment: Since the rest of my program which would use it is written in C++, a C++ way to implement it would do it. However, since I'm interested in high efficiency, a C implementation would be fine as well (even though I avoid mixing up C and C++ code, for the sake of efficiency, I would do it ;-) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The termin that can help you: `enchanced suffix array`, which is used to describe suffix array with various other arrays in order to replace suffix tree ([lcp](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866703000650), child).

These can be some of the examples:

https://code.google.com/p/esaxx/ **ESAXX**

http://bibiserv.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/mkesa/ **MKESA**

The esaxx one seems to be doing what you want, plus, it has example enumSubstring.cpp how to use it.

---

If you take a look at the referenced [paper](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEsQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebglimpse.net%2Fpubs%2Fsuffix.pdf&ei=szHXVMHdF8TZ7gbIu4DwCQ&usg=AFQjCNFj4JQQ2S1vdKZ09py7_SLZ45m_SA&bvm=bv.85464276,d.ZGU), it mentions an useful property `(4.2)`. Since SO does not support math, there is no point to copy it here.

I've done quick implementation, it uses segment tree:

```
// note that arrSize is O(n)
// int arrSize = 2 * 2 ^ (log(N) + 1) + 1; // start from 1

// LCP = new int[N];
// fill the LCP...
// LCP_LR = new int[arrSize];
// memset(LCP_LR, maxValueOfInteger, arrSize);
// 

// init: buildLCP_LR(1, 1, N);
// LCP_LR[1] == [1..N]
// LCP_LR[2] == [1..N/2]
// LCP_LR[3] == [N/2+1 .. N]

// rangeI = LCP_LR[i]
//   rangeILeft  = LCP_LR[2 * i]
//   rangeIRight = LCP_LR[2 * i + 1]
// ..etc
void buildLCP_LR(int index, int low, int high)
{
    if(low == high)
    {
        LCP_LR[index] = LCP[low];
        return;
    }

    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    buildLCP_LR(2*index, low, mid);
    buildLCP_LR(2*index+1, mid + 1, high);

    LCP_LR[index] = min(LCP_LR[2*index], LCP_LR[2*index + 1]);
}
```

Comment: It does not. "Enhanced suffix array" is a generic term. The OP (and the bounty I've posted) is looking for a very specific aspect of an enhanced suffix array, and this is the construction of the LCP-LR array as described in the paper cited in the OP. Specifically, this enables `O(M + logN)` pattern matching on a suffix array.

Comment: @BurntSushi5: What I mean't is that the termin leads you to closer finding perhaps some kind of solution (it lead me to ESAXX which shows how to efficiently find substrings from string).

Comment: @BurntSushi5: If you're interested in this specific paper & it's concrete implementation, I suggest you to add the paper here. Also, I did take a look: if you've managed to create LCP by using that paper (through interval tree), you already have **computed** the values of LCP-LR (you'd have to copy them to array from interval tree). Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: I feel like the OP is already incredibly specific. We'd like to do efficient pattern matching (in `O(m + logn)` time). The paper cited provides an algorithm for doing this, but it requires the LCP-LR array. So what we want is: given a suffix array (not enhanced, just the plain ol' suffix array) and the LCP array, how does one compute the LCP-LR array in `O(n)` time?

Comment: The OP links to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373453/how-does-lcp-help-in-finding-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-pattern/11374737#11374737), which says, "Moreover, there is a straight-forward recursive algorithm to compute the 2*N values of LCP-LR in O(N) time from the standard LCP array." But I don't know what it is. :-)

Comment: @BurntSushi5: Updated my post, see if that helps. Ps, "straight-forward" my ass ;)

Comment: Very nice! The bounty ends in a few hours and I won't have time to actually verify it, but it looks plausible enough to me, so I gave your answer the bounty. :-) And it certainly gives me some threads to pull on. When I actually implement it, I'll post any updates if necessary. Thank you! :-)

Comment: As far as I can see, your implementation works fine and meets my requirements :-) Could you give some advice how to use it best for string pattern matching? I've read the algo in the paper but I have still problems applying the implementation to the pseudocode :-/

Comment: I posted a new question regarding this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444226/understanding-the-algorithm-for-pattern-matching-using-an-lcp-array

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly simple implementation in C++, though the `build()` procedure builds the suffix array in `O(N lg^2 N)` time. The `lcp_compute()` procedure has linear complexity. I have used this code in many programming contests, and it has never let me down :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 200005;
char str[MAX];
int N, h, sa[MAX], pos[MAX], tmp[MAX], lcp[MAX];

bool compare(int i, int j) {
  if(pos[i] != pos[j]) return pos[i] < pos[j]; // compare by the first h chars
  i += h, j += h; // if prefvious comparing failed, use 2*h chars
  return (i < N && j < N) ? pos[i] < pos[j] : i > j; // return results
}

void build() {
  N = strlen(str);
  for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) sa[i] = i, pos[i] = str[i]; // initialize variables
  for(h=1;;h<<=1) {
    sort(sa, sa+N, compare); // sort suffixes
    for(int i=0; i<N-1; ++i) tmp[i+1] = tmp[i] + compare(sa[i], sa[i+1]); // bucket suffixes
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) pos[sa[i]] = tmp[i]; // update pos (reverse mapping of suffix array)
    if(tmp[N-1] == N-1) break; // check if done
  }
}

void lcp_compute() {
  for(int i=0, k=0; i<N; ++i)
    if(pos[i] != N-1) {
      for(int j=sa[pos[i]+1]; str[i+k] == str[j+k];) k++;
      lcp[pos[i]] = k;
      if(k) k--;
    }
}

int main() {
  scanf("%s", str);
  build();
  for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) printf("%d\n", sa[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

**Note:** If you want the complexity of the `build()` procedure to become `O(N lg N)`, you can replace the STL sort with radix sort, but this is going to complicate the code.

**Edit:** Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Although i haven't implemented string matching with suffix array, I think I can describe you a simple non-standard, but fairly efficient algorithm for string matching. You are given two strings, the `text`, and the `pattern`. Given these string you create a new one, lets call it `concat`, which is the concatenation of the two given strings (first the `text`, then the `pattern`). You run the suffix array construction algorithm on `concat`, and you build the normal lcp array. Then, you search for a suffix of length `pattern.size()` in the suffix array you just built. Lets call its position in the suffix array `pos`. You then need two pointers `lo` and `hi`. At start `lo = hi = pos`. You decrease `lo` while `lcp(lo, pos) = pattern.size()` and you increase `hi` while `lcp(hi, pos) = pattern.size()`. Then you search for a suffix of length at least `2*pattern.size()` in the range `[lo, hi]`. If you find it, you found a match. Otherwise, no match exists.

**Edit[2]:** I will be back with an implementation as soon as I have one...

**Edit[3]:**

Here it is:

```
// It works assuming you have builded the concatenated string and
// computed the suffix and the lcp arrays
// text.length() ---> tlen
// pattern.length() ---> plen
// concatenated string: str

bool match(int tlen, int plen) {
  int total = tlen + plen;
  int pos = -1;
  for(int i=0; i<total; ++i)
    if(total-sa[i] == plen)
      { pos = i; break; }
  if(pos == -1) return false; 
  int lo, hi;
  lo = hi = pos;
  while(lo-1 >= 0 && lcp[lo-1] >= plen) lo--;
  while(hi+1 <  N && lcp[hi] >= plen) hi++;
  for(int i=lo; i<=hi; ++i)
    if(total-sa[i] >= 2*plen)
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I already have an efficient construction implementation. However as stated in the question, I am particularly interested in an implementation that can be used for efficient pattern matching. As far as I know, this is not possible by only using the "plain" LCP and array because of the lack of being able to check every possible match. Correct me if I'm wrong here ;-)

Comment: @Paddre I added the code for the `match` procedure to my answer

Comment: I could manage to test it.
First: you should mention, that the terminating symbol (often referred to as `#` or `$`) must be added by the user and is not part of the SA construction mechanism. Once I found out it was clear from your code, but not what I expected having worked with lots of other SA/LCP implementations before.

Second: The matching does not seem to work properly. I tried `"vwvwxy#` as `text` and `"vwx"` as `pattern` (i.e. `concat = "vwvwxy#vwx") and `match()` returned `false`.

Comment: @Paddre You shouldn't add a terminating symbol. In the case you mentioned `concat` should be `"vwvwxyvwx"`. Try it, and you will see that `match()` returns `true`.

Comment: Nope. with `str="vwvwxyvwx"`, `match(6,1)` returns `false`. (SA: `{0,6,2,1,7,3,8,4,5}`)

Comment: @Paddre You should call `match(6, 3)`, not `match(6, 1)`. Also make sure that you build the lcp array the same way as I do. In my code, `lcp[i]` denotes the longest common prefix between `sa[i]` and `sa[i+1]`. If in your code `lcp[i]` denotes the longest common prefix between `sa[i]` and `sa[i-1]`, then the match procedure doesn't work properly...

Comment: Sorry the `match(6,1)` was a typo. My mistake was that I forgot to invoke `lcp_compute()` your code works fine thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17763563/1505341) is a nice post including some code to help you better understand LCP array and comparison implementation.

I understand your desire is the code, rather than implementing your own.
Although written in Java [this is an implementation of Suffix Array with LCP](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/63suffix/SuffixArray.java.html) by Sedgewick and Wayne from their [Algorithms booksite](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/). It should save you some time and should not be tremendously hard to port to C/C++.

[LCP array construction](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/tpkarkka/opetus/11s/spa/lecture10.pdf) in pseudo for those who might want more information about the algorithm.

Comment: Unfortunately none of them gives me information about constructing LCP arrays which are appropriate for efficient pattern matching

Answer (score 0):

I think @Erti-Chris Eelmaa 's algorithm is wrong.

```
L ... 'M ... M ... M' ... R
       |-----|-----|
```

Left sub range and right sub range should **all** contains M. Therefore we cannot do normal segment tree partition for LCP-LR array.
Code should look like

```
def lcp_from_i_j(i, j): # means [i, j] not [i, j)
    if (j-i<1) return lcp_2_elem(i, j)
    return lcp_merge(lcp_from_i_j(i, (i+j)/2), lcp_from_i_j((i+j)/2, j)
```

The left and the right sub ranges overlap. The segment tree supports range-min query. However, range min between [a,b] is not equal to lcp between [a,b]. LCP array is continuous, simple range-min would not work!