# How do we Construct LCP-LR array from LCP array?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching, suffix-array

To find the number of occurrences of a given string P ( length m ) in a text T ( length N )

We must use binary search against the suffix array of T.

The issue with using standard binary search ( without the LCP information ) is that in each of the O(log N) comparisons you need to make, you compare P to the current entry of the suffix array, which means a full string comparison of up to m characters. So the complexity is O(m*log N).

The LCP-LR array helps improve this to O(m+log N).
[know more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array)

How we precompute LCP-LR array from LCP array?

And How does LCP-LR help in finding the number of occurrences of a pattern?

Please Explain the Algorithm with Example

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does LCP help in finding the number of occurences of a pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373453/how-does-lcp-help-in-finding-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-pattern)

Comment: but algorithm is not explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// note that arrSize is O(n)
// int arrSize = 2 * 2 ^ (log(N) + 1) + 1; // start from 1

// LCP = new int[N];
// fill the LCP...
// LCP_LR = new int[arrSize];
// memset(LCP_LR, maxValueOfInteger, arrSize);
// 

// init: buildLCP_LR(1, 1, N);
// LCP_LR[1] == [1..N]
// LCP_LR[2] == [1..N/2]
// LCP_LR[3] == [N/2+1 .. N]

// rangeI = LCP_LR[i]
//   rangeILeft  = LCP_LR[2 * i]
//   rangeIRight = LCP_LR[2 * i + 1]
// ..etc
void buildLCP_LR(int index, int low, int high)
{
    if(low == high)
    {
        LCP_LR[index] = LCP[low];
        return;
    }

    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    buildLCP_LR(2*index, low, mid);
    buildLCP_LR(2*index+1, mid + 1, high);

    LCP_LR[index] = min(LCP_LR[2*index], LCP_LR[2*index + 1]);
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28385677/1428052

Comment: We can construct LCP Array using segment tree in O(n) but each operation on segment tree takes O(log n). How can we improve this to O(1) ? Is it possible?

Comment: the LCP-LR should precompute all possible results so you won't need to divide it to find what you need

Comment: The computation of `mid = (low + high) / 2` will overflow on large arrays. Consider changing it to `mid = low + (high - low) / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Not having enough reps to comment so posting. Is anybody able to create the LCP-LR using @Abhijeet Ashok Muneshwar solution. For ex for text- mississippi the Suffix array-

### 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

### 10  7   1   4   0   9   8   3   6   2   5

The LCP array will be

### 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

### 1   1   4   0   0   1   0   2   1   3   0

And LCP-LR will be

### 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

### 1   1   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   1   3

But the LCP-LR obtained using the code is not same as above.
To the method buildLCP_LR i am passing index=0, low=0, high=n